# is there a DWT function in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

is there a DWT (discrete wavelet transform ) function in opencv ??  else if anyone have link of its implementation in c++

Comment: Please support the Area 51 proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1691/signal-image-video-processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that openCV does not have an implementation of the DWT algorithm, but a quick google search turns up two results which may be relevant.

[First is a result from Koders code search](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid9FB2AEB53947472BB2665335D1B4DE6A8A3EB277.aspx?s=%22Srinivas%22#L14), which is an implementation designed to process MPEG4 frames for an image decoding program.

There is also a [google code project, wavelet1d](http://code.google.com/p/wavelet1d/) which is a version designed to process a 1d array of data.

You may be able to use those two implementations to build your own suitable for your uses?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe OpenCV has that functionality.

[This page might be useful](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/2D_FWT_lib.aspx?msg=3017574).